# How can torch multiply two 10000*10000 matrices in almost zero time? Why does the speed change so much from 349 ms down to 999 µs?

Tags: python, performance, jupyter-notebook, pytorch

Here is an excerpt from Jupyter:

In `[1]`:

```py
import torch, numpy as np, datetime
cuda = torch.device('cuda')
```

In `[2]`:

```py
ac = torch.randn(10000, 10000).to(cuda)
bc = torch.randn(10000, 10000).to(cuda)
%time cc = torch.matmul(ac, bc)
print(cc[0, 0], torch.sum(ac[0, :] * bc[:, 0]))
```

> Wall time: 349 ms
>
> tensor(17.0374, device='cuda:0') tensor(17.0376, device='cuda:0')

The time is low but still reasonable (0.35 sec for 1e12 multiplications)

But if we repeat the same:

```py
ac = torch.randn(10000, 10000).to(cuda)
bc = torch.randn(10000, 10000).to(cuda)
%time cc = torch.matmul(ac, bc)
print(cc[0, 0], torch.sum(ac[0, :] * bc[:, 0]))
```

> Wall time: 999 µs
>
> tensor(-78.7172, device='cuda:0') tensor(-78.7173, device='cuda:0')

`1e12` multiplications in `1ms`?!

Why did the time change from 349ms to 1ms?

Info:

- Tested on GeForce RTX 2070;
- Can be reproduced on Google Colab.

Comment: The obvious way of doing matrix multiply is O(N^3), but isn't there a way that does it faster, perhaps O(N^2*log(N))?

Comment: @RickJames there is no known way to do it in O(N^(2*log(N))). There are ways to do it theoretically faster, but in practice they are not usable, except one which takes N**(log(7)/log(2)) which is approximately N**2.81, but even it is not used because of big constant and problems with numerical stability.

Comment: Thanks.  That's probably what I am remembering (incorrectly).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is already a discussion about this on Discuss PyTorch: [Measuring GPU tensor operation speed](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/measuring-gpu-tensor-operation-speed/2513).

I'd like to highlight two comments from that thread:

- From [@apaszke](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/measuring-gpu-tensor-operation-speed/2513/4):

> [...] the GPU executes all operations asynchronously, so you need to insert proper barriers for your benchmarks to be correct

- From [@ngimel](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/measuring-gpu-tensor-operation-speed/2513/5):

> I believe cublas handles are allocated lazily now, which means that first operation requiring cublas will have an overhead of creating cublas handle, and that includes some internal allocations. So there’s no way to avoid it other than calling some function requiring cublas before the timing loop.

---

Basically, you have to `synchronize()` to have a proper measurement:

```py
import torch

x = torch.randn(10000, 10000).to("cuda")
w = torch.randn(10000, 10000).to("cuda")
# ensure that context initialization finish before you start measuring time
torch.cuda.synchronize()

%time y = x.mm(w.t()); torch.cuda.synchronize()
```

> CPU times: user 288 ms, sys: 191 ms, total: 479 ms
>
> Wall time: 492 ms

```py
x = torch.randn(10000, 10000).to("cuda")
w = torch.randn(10000, 10000).to("cuda")
# ensure that context initialization finish before you start measuring time
torch.cuda.synchronize()

%time y = x.mm(w.t()); torch.cuda.synchronize()
```

> CPU times: user 237 ms, sys: 231 ms, total: 468 ms
>
> Wall time: 469 ms

Comment: tried this code on Google Colab, it seems around `400 ms` is a reasonable duration. I think this is the correct answer.

Comment: @iyunbo In fact, the measurements I posted on the answer come from Google Colab :) BTW, the answer is a community wiki because it basically comes from the Discuss PyTorch thread, after a small discussion with another user (a_guest) on the comments of the other answer.

Comment: This section of the CUDA Best practices guide might be relevant here: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html#using-cpu-timers It explicitly explains the issues with async calls and the sychronization that may be necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Docs say:

```
torch.cuda.synchronize()
```

> Waits for all kernels in all streams on a CUDA device to complete.

In fact, this tells Python: *stop, and wait until the operation fully finished.*

**Otherwise, the `%time` returns immediately after issuing a command.**

This would be the correct way to test the time. Note two times `torch.cuda.synchronize()` first one to wait for the tensors to move on cuda, and second to wait until the command completes on GPU.

```
import torch

x = torch.randn(10000, 10000).to("cuda")
w = torch.randn(10000, 10000).to("cuda")
torch.cuda.synchronize()

%timeit -n 10 y = x.matmul(w.t()); torch.cuda.synchronize() #10 loops, best of 3: 531 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

GPU memory cache i'd guess. Try torch.cuda.empty_cache() after each run.

Comment: I thought about that as well, but `ac` and `bc` are supposed to be random. Is that still valid somehow?

Comment: I just tried and `empty_cache(...)` has no effect in this case.

Comment: [`empty_cache`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/cuda.html#cuda-memory-management) only releases *unused* cached memory, so you might want to slip in `del ac; del bc; del cc` before the `empty_cache`. It could also be that pytorch requests more memory from the GPU, so you might want to monitor [`torch.cuda.memory_allocated`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/cuda.html#torch.cuda.memory_allocated) and [`torch.cuda.max_memory_allocated`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/cuda.html#torch.cuda.max_memory_allocated) before and after the operations.

Comment: @a_guest I also tried to `del` the vars and, still, same timings... the question is not mine, but I am interested on why this happens

Comment: @Berriel Could you monitor memory usage before and after each of the steps / operations (including `del`'ing the vars) to check whether a) additional memory is requested for the second multiplication and b) the memory really is released by `empty_cache`?

Comment: @a_guest everything happened as expected, yet, second run is still running on ~1ms: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1kYE-LFLoBENhmLyIMRca_KlTvId_UzMj

Comment: @Berriel That shows releasing memory works fine. It might be though that for the first `matmul` pytorch needs to request additional memory and hence takes more time to run - for the second run this memory is then already cached. Hence could you add the output for `torch.cuda.memory_cached(), torch.cuda.max_memory_cached()` as well to your stats func and check whether additional memory is requested (also printing stats after `a = ...`, `b = ...`)? And best to leave out that `print` statement to really narrow it down.

Comment: @Berriel For example could you check the following snippet: https://www.codepile.net/pile/wkp8dwkr

Comment: It runs as expected. I think it has something to do with GPU warm-up. There is a discussion here as well: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/measuring-gpu-tensor-operation-speed/2513

Comment: @Berriel Hm I'm not sure since 1 ms for ~1e12 operations on that GPU sounds way too small (estimation yields the first timing result: 1e12 / 2304 / 1410e6 Hz ~= 308 ms). Could you try timing manually and using [`torch.cuda.synchronize`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/cuda.html#torch.cuda.synchronize) as described in [this post](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/measuring-gpu-tensor-operation-speed/2513/4)?

Comment: @a_guest Yes, without `synchronize(...)`, the timings are unreliable. I posted an answer as a community wiki, since it basically comes from that Discuss PyTorch thread.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196113/discussion-between-a-guest-and-berriel).